# how to take array with specific char?

Tags: php, arrays

i have array 
Example :

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "{what}" [1]=> string(5) "[why]" [2]=> string(5) "(how)" }
```

and then how to take array with specific char ("{") ?

Comment: How about `array_filter()` ?

Comment: @Dwi Share the code you had tried to solve the problem also in the question!

Comment: @NarenMurali sorry sir , i just write array example in this question :( I'm sorry my bad

Comment: @Arvind oh thanks sir . i dont know what function to fix this  .

Comment: @DwiYudiRayiA Even if what you tried doesn't work, its expected you share what you have atempted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through your array and filter out the values you are interested in, in your case i guess it's the values that contain the Char "{"

A possible implementation:

```
$result = array_filter($your_array, function($value) {
   return preg_match('/{/', $value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Is my understanding here correct? You want to get items in array that has a "{" Character. Then why not just loop over it and check the item if it has that character and push it in a new array.

```
    $array_with_sp_char = array();    
    foreach ($arr_items as $item) {
       if (strpos($item, '{') !== FALSE) {
           array_push($array_with_sp_char, $item);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$array = [
    "{what}",
    "[why]",
    "(how)"
];

$array = array_filter($array, function($value) {
    return strpos($value, '{') !== false;
});

print_r($array);
```

That will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {what}
)
```